# How do I Optimize my C++ key-value program to have a faster runtime?

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, key-value

This is a2.hpp, and is the program that can be edited, as far as I know the code is correct, just too slow. I am honestly lost here, I know my for loops are probably whats slowing me down so much, maybe use an iterator?

```
// <algorithm>, <list>, <vector>
// YOU CAN CHANGE/EDIT ANY CODE IN THIS FILE AS LONG AS SEMANTICS IS UNCHANGED

#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

class key_value_sequences {

private:
  std::list<std::vector<int>> seq;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> keyref;

public:
    // YOU SHOULD USE C++ CONTAINERS TO AVOID RAW POINTERS
    // IF YOU DECIDE TO USE POINTERS, MAKE SURE THAT YOU MANAGE MEMORY PROPERLY
    // IMPLEMENT ME: SHOULD RETURN SIZE OF A SEQUENCE FOR GIVEN KEY
    // IF NO SEQUENCE EXISTS FOR A GIVEN KEY RETURN 0
    int size(int key) const;

    // IMPLEMENT ME: SHOULD RETURN POINTER TO A SEQUENCE FOR GIVEN KEY
    // IF NO SEQUENCE EXISTS FOR A GIVEN KEY RETURN nullptr
    const int* data(int key) const;

    // IMPLEMENT ME: INSERT VALUE INTO A SEQUENCE IDENTIFIED BY GIVEN KEY
    void insert(int key, int value);
}; // class key_value_sequences


int key_value_sequences::size(int key) const {
    //checks if the key is invalid or the count vector is empty.
  if(key<0 || keyref[key].empty()) return 0;
    // sub tract 1 because the first element is the key to access the count
  return keyref[key].size() -1;
}

const int* key_value_sequences::data(int key) const {
      //checks if key index or ref vector is invalid
    if(key<0 || keyref.size() < static_cast<unsigned int>(key+1)) {
      return nullptr;
    }
      // ->at(1) accesses the count (skipping the key) with a pointer
    return &keyref[key].at(1);
}

void key_value_sequences::insert(int key, int value) {
      //checks if key is valid and if the count vector needs to be resized
    if(key>=0 && keyref.size() < static_cast<unsigned int>(key+1)) {
      keyref.resize(key+1);
      std::vector<int> val;
      seq.push_back(val);
      seq.back().push_back(key);
      seq.back().push_back(value);
      keyref[key] = seq.back();
    }
      //the index is already valid
    else if(key >=0) keyref[key].push_back(value);
}

#endif // A2_HPP
```

This is a2.cpp, this just tests the functionality of a2.hpp, this code cannot be changed

```
// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE !!!
// YOUR CODE MUST BE CONTAINED IN a2.hpp ONLY

#include <iostream>
#include "a2.hpp"


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    key_value_sequences A;

    {
        key_value_sequences T;
        // k will be our key
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {  //the actual tests will have way more than 10 sequences.
            // v is our value
            // here we are creating 10 sequences:
            // key = 0, sequence = (0)
            // key = 1, sequence = (0 1)
            // key = 2, sequence = (0 1 2)
            // ...
            // key = 9, sequence = (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
            for (int v = 0; v < k + 1; ++v) T.insert(k, v);
        }

        T = T;
        key_value_sequences V = T;
        A = V;
    }
    std::vector<int> ref;

    if (A.size(-1) != 0) {
        std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
        if (A.size(k) != k + 1) {
            std::cout << "fail";
            return -1;
        } else {
            ref.clear();
            for (int v = 0; v < k + 1; ++v) ref.push_back(v);
            if (!std::equal(ref.begin(), ref.end(), A.data(k))) {
                std::cout << "fail 3 " << A.data(k) << " " << ref[k];
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "pass" << std::endl;

    return 0;
} // main
```

If anyone could help me improve my codes efficiency I would really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far to investigate the issue?

Comment: You could simulate a `hash_map`/`unordered_map` with a `std::vector<std::list<std::vector<int>>>`

Comment: What should it do?

Comment: @EvilTeach Originally I had a for loop inside a for loop for every function but I realized it wasn't necessary, then I got rid of as many global variables as I could. Would changing my int's to unsigned int's improve runtime as well? I also notice every function has the same for loop followed by the same if statement, so would recursion be possible?

Comment: @Surt It is meant to take in a key-value pair, store the key in a vector and then create a vector of vectors to store the key vector at index 0, and a vector of every value with that keky after

Comment: 'seq' is not used for anything useful?

Comment: The answer to your question is simple: **Profile**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will join Sorin in saying don't use std::list if avoidable.

So you use `key` as direct index, where does it say it is none-negative? where does it say its less than 100000000?

```
void key_value_sequences::insert(int key, int value) {
  //checks if key is valid and if the count vector needs to be resized
  if(key>=0 && keyref.size() < static_cast<unsigned int>(key+1)) {
    keyref.resize(key+1); // could be large
    std::vector<int> val; // don't need this temporary.
    seq.push_back(val); // seq is useless?
    seq.back().push_back(key);
    seq.back().push_back(value);
    keyref[key] = seq.back(); // we now have 100000000-1 empty indexes 
  }
  //the index is already valid
  else if(key >=0) keyref[key].push_back(value);
}
```

Can it be done faster? depending on your `key` range yes it can. You will need to implement a flat_map or hash_map.

C++11 concept code for a flat_map version.

```
// effectively a binary search
auto key_value_sequences::find_it(int key) { // type should be iterator
  return std::lower_bound(keyref.begin(), keyref.end(), [key](const auto& check){
    return check[0] < key; // key is 0-element
  });
}      


void key_value_sequences::insert(int key, int value) {
  auto found = find_it(key);

  // at the end or not found
  if (found == keyref.end() || found->front() != key) {
    found = keyref.emplace(found, key); // add entry
  }
  found->emplace_back(value); // update entry, whether new or old. 
}

const int* key_value_sequences::data(int key) const {
  //checks if key index or ref vector is invalid
  auto found = find_it(key);
  if (found == keyref.end())
    return nullptr;
  // ->at(1) accesses the count (skipping the key) with a pointer
  return found->at(1);
}
```

(hope I got that right ...)

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not convinced your code is correct. In insert, if they key is valid you create a new vector and insert it into sequence. Sounds wrong, as that should only happen if you have a new key, but if your tests pass it might be fine.

Performance wise:

- Avoid std::list. Linked lists have terrible performance on today's hardware because they break pipelineing, caching and pre-fetching. Always use std::vector instead. If the payload is really big and you are worried about copies use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`
- Try to avoid copying vectors. In your code you have `keyref[key] = seq.back()` which copies the vector, but should be fine since it's only one element.

Otherwise there's no obvious performance problems. Try to benchmark and profile your program and see where the slow parts are. Usually there's one or two places that you need to optimize and get great performance. If it's still too slow, ask another question where you post your results so that we can better understand the problem.